# Is M defined as below a martingale?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $f\in L^2$. Let $$Z_t:=\int_0^t f(s)dB_s.$$

We know that
$$
L=\exp\left(\int_0^t f(s)dB_s-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t f(s)^2 ds\right),
$$
is a martingale.

Now, let $\sigma$ be another random variable independent of $B_t$. Assume that the characteristic function of $\sigma$:
$$
E[e^{it\sigma}]=\frac{B_1(2t)}{t}
$$
where $B_1(\cdot)$ is the Bessel function (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

Can we say that
$$
M=\exp\left(\int_0^t \sigma f(s)dB_s-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \sigma^2 f(s)^2 ds\right)
$$
is still a martingale?

---

I try to check that with the definition of martingale...

By the comment below, by Novikov's condition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov%27s_condition) we need to check
$$
E\left(\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\int_0^T \sigma^2 f^2(s)ds\right)\right)<\infty
$$

But I am stuck on this step...

Comment: You need $\sigma^{2}$ in the second integral. The proof follows by just conditioning on $\sigma$.

Comment: Make sure to verify whether the second integral is $dt$ or $dB_t$. There's a difference.

Comment: @Hamdiken Thanks! Yes, that is $dt$.

Comment: @geetha290krm What do you mean? I try to prove $E[M(t)|F_s]=M(t)$.

Comment: @Hermi what means is that the second $ds$ part is the variance of the first $dB_s$ part. By definition, the variance can be obtained through the Itô isometry, which will get you a $\sigma^2$ in the second part. Finally, with some conditions on $\sigma$ you can deduce it's a martingale.

Comment: @Hamdiken Ok, so $M=\exp\left(\int_0^t \sigma f(s)dB_s-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \sigma^2f(s)^2 ds\right)$ is a martingale?

Comment: It is provided that the [Novikov condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov%27s_condition) holds.

Comment: @Hamdiken Thanks. I add the assumption of MGF of $\sigma$. Dose it enough to determine that is a martingale? I also add my work.. I am stuck how to verify the condition...

Answer (score 1):

Which Bessel function do you have in mind? (There are several, and your notation $B_1$ is non-standard.)

A more appropriate condition for testing whether you have a martingale might be Kazamaki's: If for each $t>0$ you have
$$
\sup_{T\le t} E[\exp(\sigma Z_T)]<\infty,
$$
then $(M_t)$ is a martingale. The supremum here is taken over all stopping times $T$ that are bounded above by $t$. For this you need to work with the mgf of $\sigma$.